# Collision under $-k/r$ potential

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

In the case of an elastic collision between particles traveling in opposite directions, the lighter particle always bounces back. How is this possible when the collision happens due to an attractive potential like $-k/r$ (angular momentum = $0$ in this case). Under the effect of a $-k/r$ potential the particles should fall into each other. What happens after that? (In non-relativistic classical framework).

Answer (score 1):

If at the center of mass of the two classical particles  are at rest, the attractive 1/r potential will give them equal and opposite momentum  and they will merge into one mass.

For one of the particles at rest targeted by another particle with momentum :

> [Scattering of a probe particle on a target](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-7091-8866-8_1?noAccess=true) is said to be elastic if
> there is *no change in the internal energy of both.* The maximum
> $ΔE$ of kinetic energy the probe particle can transfer to a target at
> rest is given by the c*onservation of energy* $E_o$ and momentum $p_o$
> in a head-on elastic collision

italic mine

Answer (score 0):

Since the only stable point with potential is the origin, particles will try to marge and fall to the origin in the stable region. Anyway this is an attractive central potential and if the elastic coefficient $1$ then they will collide with each other forever.

Comment: This is true for the case when the total energy (sum of kinetic and potential energy) of the particles is less than zero. When the total energy is equal to or greater than zero there are no bound states.

Comment: Because there has a possibility of bound state due to Barthhand theroem